# I request to write reason if you are marking a question as duplicate to other question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, duplicates

I recently asked a question:

> [Why not Sun's gravity affect angular momentum of Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392587/)

Then QMechanic, a moderator of this web site marked my question as a duplicate of:

> [Tidal force of Sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111685/)

So I searched whether my question is duplicate, but tidal effect is very different to what I expected. I even know the perfect solution to my question. I even verified by some famous books. I request you to write reason for marking the question as duplicate.

Comment: I can understand your frustration, and request that you also understand that moderators could sometimes be overloaded with moderation duties, so their practices might be optimized for "high average throughput". @rob's answer explains how we can work with that practical limitation.

Comment: If you already have the perfect solution why the fuss?

Answer (score 8):

We do have a procedure in place where users of the site can vote to reopen closed questions, and I see that your question currently has one reopen vote.

The best way for you to speed this process along is for you to edit your question with some text like "it's been suggested that this question is a duplicate of [link]. But that's a question about X, while I'm asking about Y. Are they perhaps related because of Z?" The clearer you can be about what you're hoping to get from us, and how it's different from the answers we already have, the better we'll be able to help you.